# Under which circumstances textAlign property works in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, text-alignment

In the code below, `textAlign` property doesn't work. If you remove `DefaultTextStyle` wrapper which is several levels above, `textAlign` starts to work.

Why and how to ensure it is always working?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new DefaultTextStyle(style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0), child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new Text("Should be left", textAlign: TextAlign.left,),
        new Text("Should be right", textAlign: TextAlign.right,)
      ],))
    );
  }
}
```

---

Both approaches, suggested by Remi apparently don't work "in the wild". Here is an example I nested both inside rows and columns. First approach doesn't do align and second approach makes application just crash:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, child: new DefaultTextStyle(
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.white),
            child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
              new Row(children: <Widget>[
                new Container(color: Colors.grey, child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
                  new Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: new Text("left")),
                  new Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: new Text("right")),
                ],)),
                new Container(color: Colors.grey, child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
                  new Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: new Text("left")),
                  new Align(alignment: Alignment.centerRight, child: new Text("right")),
                ],)),
              ],),
              /*new Row(children: <Widget>[
                new Container(color: Colors.grey, child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
                  new SizedBox(width: double.infinity, child: new Text("left", textAlign: TextAlign.left,)),
                  new SizedBox(width: double.infinity, child: new Text("right", textAlign: TextAlign.right)),
                ],)),
                new Container(color: Colors.grey, child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
                  new SizedBox(width: double.infinity, child: new Text("left", textAlign: TextAlign.left)),
                  new SizedBox(width: double.infinity, child: new Text("right", textAlign: TextAlign.right)),
                ],)),
              ],)*/]
    )));
  }
}
```

---

What I get from code is

[image]

i.e. text is centered, ignoring alignment of `Align` element.

Comment: Why do you use DefaultTextStyle as a container for 2 text children?

Comment: Why wouldn't I?

Answer (score 339, accepted):

`DefaultTextStyle` is unrelated to the problem. Removing it simply uses the default style, which is far bigger than the one you used so it hides the problem.

---

`textAlign` aligns the text in the space occupied by `Text` when that occupied space is bigger than the actual content.

The thing is, inside a `Column`, your `Text` takes the bare minimum space. It is then the `Column` that aligns its children using `crossAxisAlignment` which defaults to `center`.

An easy way to catch such behavior is by wrapping your texts like this :

```
Container(
   color: Colors.red,
   child: Text(...)
)
```

Which using the code you provided, render the following :

[image]

The problem suddenly becomes obvious: `Text` don't take the whole `Column` width.

---

You now have a few solutions.

You can wrap your `Text` into an `Align` to mimic `textAlign` behavior

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Text(
          "Should be left",
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Which will render the following :

[image]

or you can force your `Text` to fill the `Column` width.

Either by specifying `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` on `Column`, or by using `SizedBox` with an infinite `width`.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Text(
          "Should be left",
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

which renders the following:

[image]

In that example, it is `TextAlign` that placed the text to the left.

Comment: But don't you agree, that all you described are tricks and workarounds, meaning bad design of the library?

Comment: This is definitely not a trick/workaround. This is the official solution. Flutter uses a constraint-based layout with composition at its core. It is  the functional programming of Layout. It is absolutely awesome

Comment: In first case you specified "left" twice, in second case you specified infinite width. These are definitely tricks despite they are official and functional.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to remove the `textAlign` on the `Align` example. Fixed. And the "infinite width" in flutter simply says "I want as much space as possible".

Comment: Okay, then the first way is better, although it still doesn't work for me outside this simple example...

Comment: P.S. Also strictly speaking, it is not functional, when outside affects inside...

Comment: But it is functional here. We didn't change the content, we changed the props passed to the "function". In flutter these props are constraints.

Comment: It's going to be hard to help you without seing your problem though. Maybe make another question with a more precise example

Comment: You most likely didn't understand something. I can't help without seeing your code though

Comment: See my update please. I nested both you approaches into rows and cols. In first row I put your first approach and in second one I put second. First doesn't work, second crashes the renderer (because of infinite width, uncomment to see).

Comment: Duh, that's a radically different layout. Both your examples need a different solution. Considering this, do you mind creating a new question?

Comment: But in short, the solution is to wrap both `Container` into an `Expanded`

Comment: Why is it different? I missed something? I can't create question on each my layout, I want general approach working in predictable way.

Comment: The `Align` thing worked here too. The problem here is that it's your columns which don't fill the row. To expand widgets on the main axis of `Column`/`Row` you need to wrap them into `Expanded`.

Comment: I wrapped both aligns into container, which is grey, it is evident, that it is rectangular and there is space to align. Nevertheless, alignment doesn't happen

Comment: Use expanded, not align

Comment: Your second problem is not related to alignment. You simply want one child of a row/column to expand in the row/column main axis.

Comment: I don't understand why. See my screenshot. Text is obviously centered, i.e. `Align` is just ignored without any reason. Space between cells is unrelated problem.

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question. The question is when does textalign work, and your answer is to use something else...not to mention that means every text element needs both and align AND a container around it....it's a ridiculous workaround.

Comment: The answer is it never works and it's a bug. It shouldn't be aligning itself to ITSELF..it should be aligning itself to the width of the column it's in...

Comment: The `Container` has nothing to do with the solutions. It's just there for debug purpose. Similarly, the second example shows how to use `textAlign` instead of using `Align` wiget.

Answer (score 106):

Specify `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` in your column

Comment: Shouldn't that be?: crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start

Comment: That wouldn't work since he has one text widget aligned left and one to the right...

Comment: @TSR this only work if the column already has one element that occupies the entire width (for example a `Row` would work, or `Align( ... centerLeft)`

Answer (score 33):

In Colum widget Text alignment will be centred automatically, so use  `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` to align start.

```
Column( 
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, 
    children: <Widget>[ 
    Text(""),
    Text(""),
    ]);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, due to the accurate explanation.

Answer (score 27):

`textAlign` property only works when there is a more space left for the `Text`'s content. Below are 2 examples which shows when textAlign has impact and when not.

---

#### No impact

For instance, in this example, it won't have any impact because there is no extra space for the content of the `Text`.

```
Text(
  "Hello",
  textAlign: TextAlign.end, // no impact
),
```

[image]

---

#### Has impact

If you wrap it in a `Container` and provide extra `width` such that it has more extra space.

```
Container(
  width: 200,
  color: Colors.orange,
  child: Text(
    "Hello",
    textAlign: TextAlign.end, // has impact
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: You can also test it with `Very \n Good Morning`

Answer (score 13):

Set `alignment: Alignment.centerRight` in Container:

```
Container(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child:Text(
       "Hello",
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the container, It will help you to set the alignment.

```
Widget _buildListWidget({Map reminder}) {
return Container(
  color: Colors.amber,
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  height: 80,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          reminder['title'],
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Colors.black,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Text(
          reminder['Date'],
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            color: Colors.grey,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For maximum flexibility, I usually prefer working with SizedBox like this:

```
Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  SizedBox(
                                      width: 235,
                                      child: Text('Hey, ')),
                                  SizedBox(
                                      width: 110,
                                      child: Text('how are'),
                                  SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                      child: Text('you?'))
                                ],
                              )
```

I've experienced problems with text alignment when using alignment in the past, whereas sizedbox always does the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can align text anywhere in the scaffold or container except center:-

Its works for me anywhere in my application:-

```
new Text(

                "Nextperience",

//i have setted in center.

                textAlign: TextAlign.center,

//when i want it left.

 //textAlign: TextAlign.left,

//when i want it right.

 //textAlign: TextAlign.right,

                style: TextStyle(

                    fontSize: 16,

                    color: Colors.blue[900],

                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),

              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter defaults to sizing children before parents unless you say otherwise.

Since your Text has no other children, its size is the minimum required to show all the text.

The easy way to tell Flutter you want your widget to fill its parent is to use a widget like `Expanded` with a `Row`.

```dart
return Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        "Hello, World!",
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
      )
    );
  ]
)
```

This works because `Row` has infinite constraints on the x-axis and Expanded causes its child to fill the remaining space on the x-axis.

Answer (score -3):

```
Text(' Use textAlign: TextAlign.center',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,fontSize: 20,),

            textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
```

Always use textAlign When trying to direct you text