# What is the difference between centerTitle and TextAlign.centre?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't get the title in the center of my `appBar` using `textAlign: TextAlign center`. What is the difference between them?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638176/under-which-circumstances-textalign-property-works-in-flutter/51639681#51639681

Comment: Where is your minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`centerTitle` is a property of `AppBar`, and it is used to center the title, which you generally see in iOS design pattern.

[image]

---

On the other hand, `TextAlign.center` is `Text`'s `align` value. This only works if your `Text` is long enough (means there are some more spaces for text), see my [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57231608/6618622) for more information.