# Change the text direction in the AppBar from going LTR to RTL flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

I have an application that I'm building and in it, I have an `AppBar`. My text is in Arabic and I want to make the text place change from `LTR` (left-to-right) to `RTL` (right-to-left)

Here is a screenshot of the `AppBar`

[image]

And this is the code for my `AppBar`

```
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolBarHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(
        kAppBarTitleFirst,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So the question is:- How can I get the text `عنوان التطبيق` to be in the place of the red that I marked (see screenshot above)

Comment: Anyone who wants a better solution for this has to see the pinned answer and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51639681/12831576 to get the full answer

Comment: I also found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535185/right-to-left-rtl-in-flutter , might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **textDirection property** of Text widget.

```
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolBarHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(
        kAppBarTitleFirst,
        textDirection:TextDirection.rtl  // ← add this line
      ),
    ); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not working... I'm not changing the TextDirection I just want to change the whole thing to the right

Comment: Bur in your question,you mention that you want عنوان التطبيق`  to be in the place of the red

Comment: After seeing this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51639681/12831576 your answer makes sense to me

Answer (score 7):

if you want Text direction right to left in your entire app and not just on the  App Bar you can provide a `Directionality` to `MaterialApp`

```
MaterialApp(
 builder: (context, child) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: child,
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

force the whole app to be from left to right.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text(
                'عنوان التطبيق',
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

also here is the changes on the orignal demo flutter

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Directionality( // <-- Add this Directionality
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: MyHomePage(title: 'الصفحة الرئيسية لعرض Flutter Demo')),
    );
  }
}
```