# Why is a Text element centered and how to align it to the right in Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, alignment

I have a text element which should be aligned to the left but for some reason it appears centered and I can't figure out why.

What code should be changed / added to make the `result` string aligned to the right?

```
return Positioned(
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    left: 0,
    child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 30),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                //First row here. The one below is the second row:
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.comment),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(children: [
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 10.0, left: 5.0, right: 0),
                            child: Text(
                              result, //This text is centered. Why?
                              maxLines: 7,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            )),
                      ]),
                    )
                  ],
                ),                    
              ],
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In accordance to https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html on Column-Class, the Column widget does not scroll (and in general it is considered an error to have more children in a Column than will fit in the available room). If you have a line of widgets and want them to be able to scroll if there is insufficient room, consider using a ListView. For a horizontal variant, see Row.
Also, if you only have one child, then consider using Align or Center to position the child.

For your case, you could add the property **crossAxisAlignment** to your column as following

```
... Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, ...
```

as mentioned by @nuts so the text will be align right. Here is a full example also from the above reference under https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html, that i just modified to illustrate how to do it:

```
    /// Flutter code sample for Expanded

// This example shows how to use an [Expanded] widget in a [Column] so that
// its middle child, a [Container] here, expands to fill the space.
//
// ![This results in two thin blue boxes with a larger amber box in between.](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/expanded_column.png)
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyApp({
        Key ? key
    }): super(key: key);

    static
    const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return const MaterialApp(
            title: _title,
            home: MyStatelessWidget(),
        );
    }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyStatelessWidget({
        Key ? key
    }): super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('Expanded Column Sample'),
            ),
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    children: < Widget > [
                        Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                            child: Container(
                                color: Colors.amber,
                                width: 100,
                            ),
                        ),
                        Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: < Widget > [
                                Text('We moved this text to the right')
                            ],
                        ),
                        Container(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Hope, this will help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use direction for this purpose.

For example:

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: child,
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because row or column alignment.

By default column is centering children, to change that update:

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
        ...
```

If this does not solve your problem check:
[Under which circumstances textAlign property works in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638176/under-which-circumstances-textalign-property-works-in-flutter)

More info on column/row alignment:
https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041